# Corda Node monitoring tool or explorer which can be used to show insights other than corda explorer

Tags: kotlin, corda

I need corda monitoring tool which will show insights of corda. Corda node explorer only able to show cash states only. I also try to use [corda nodepad](https://node-pad.net/) but this only works on single port currently which means on single machine single node can be shown. Is there any open source project for corda node monitoring other than Corda node explorer ? Also is there any other way to run nodepad tool for 2 nodes on same machine?

I am looking for open source project to view inside of node data...

Answer (score 0):

Corda Node Explorer isn't for monitoring nodes. It works with the Cash CorDapp to watch flows as well as showing the contents of the vault.

This is something you could easily accomplish by writing an API that exposes the contents of the vault or the state machine. The Corda Shell also shows the progress of flows if you setup progress tracker.

Take a look at the [samples](http://www.corda.net/samples) for API examples.

Answer (score 0):

Nodepad is multi nodes. It should do the trick.
The [configuration section](https://node-pad.net/wiki/index.php/Configuration) may help you get there.

[image]